# Finding values of a and b such that the given function is continuous at $ x = \frac{\pi}{4} $ and $ x = \frac{\pi}{2}$ .

Tags: continuity

> Find the values of a and b such that the given function is continuous at $ x = \frac{\pi}{4}$ and $x = \frac{\pi}{2}$. 
>   $$f(x)= \left\{\begin{matrix}
> x + a\sqrt{2} \sin x \ ;& 0\le x < \frac{\pi}{4} \\ 
> 2x\cot x + b \ ; & \frac{\pi}{4} \le x \le \frac{\pi}{2} \\ 
> a\cos 2x - b\sin x \ ; &  \frac{\pi}{2} < x \le \pi 
> \end{matrix}\right. $$

This is what I've tried yet :

**Finding LHL** : $\lim_{x\to {(\pi/4)}^{-}} f(x)$ = $x + a  $

**FINDING RHL** : $\lim_{x \to {(\pi/4)}^{+}} f(x)$ = ?

There will be two functions possible for $x\to (\pi/4)^+$ : $2x\cot x + b$ and $a\cos 2x - b \sin x$. How should I compute RHL here? I just need a hint. Thanks!

Comment: When you are coming from the $(\pi/4)^{+}$ side, you must use the second equation when evaluating the limit because you are getting arbitrarily close to $\pi/4$. When you are approaching $\pi/4$, you will not be in the region $[\pi/2, \pi]$. You do not use $a\cos(2x)-b\sin(x)$ for this reason.

Comment: Oh, got it! Thanks a lot, JessicaK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: when $x\to (\pi/4)+$, it is only a little bit bigger than $\pi/4$, i.e. much smaller than $\pi/2$.

Comment: Got it! thanks a lot for your help, Mr. Vadim.

Comment: My pleasure, glad to be of service.